# Does creating a new DbContext instance open a new connection and transaction?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

In EF6, when doing:

```
this.dataContext = new MyContext("name=contextname");
```

Does it open a new connection and transaction?

The reason is because when I call my UoW's Commit() method, the dbcontext's connection is already open.

Comment: Pretty sure it doesn't as instantiating a context works fine if you have no connection string set up.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738582.aspx - this article is for ObjectContext but DbContext is built on top of ObjectContext so I'm guessing it's very similar.

Comment: And checking the [source code](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/DbContext.cs) it looks like it is initialized with a `LazyInternalConnection` that won't be opened until needed.

Comment: Reading the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737) it mentions: _By default, the context manages connections to the database. The context opens and closes connections as needed. For example, the context opens a connection to execute a query, and then closes the connection when all the result sets have been processed._

Comment: How do you determine that it's open already?

Comment: I wrapped SaveChanges in a transaction, and it through an exception that there was already an uncommited transaction. As my unit of work is instance per request, I don't know how the connection was already open.

Comment: Behind the scenes, you have connection pooling going on. Every time you instantiate a new context, it'll reference the connection pool and reuse an existing connection, as long as it matches a similar shape (parameters) . Your transactions will be separate, but the connection might be the same. This is so you're saved the overhead and time of instantiating a new connection to the data source.